# Is there a explicit formula for Levy's area in terms of signature for higher dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, soft-question, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-path-theory

It is konwn that levy area for two dimenaional path in terms of signature is given by $A=.5*(S(x)_{a,b}^{1,2}-S(x)_{a,b}^{2,1})$ as described in equation 1.35 in the reference below. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03788.pdf The question, is there a explicit formular for area in terms of signature for higher dimensions? It should be derivable but not sure how? Any reference or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In dimensions higher than 2, what does it even mean to talk about the area "of" a path?  In dimension 3, for instance, given a curve $\gamma$, there will be lots of different bounded surfaces whose boundary is $\gamma$, and they don't all have the same area.

Comment: Let $X: [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a path. You can define Levy's stochastic area of $X$ as a matrix $A = (A^{ij})_{1\leq i, j \leq d}$ where $$ A^{ij}_{s,t} = \frac{1}{2} \underset{{s<u_i<u_2<t}}\iint \,d X^i_{u_1} \, d X^j_{u_2} - \,d X^j_{u_1} \, d X^i_{u_2},$$ provided that the integrals above can be defined well. cf. p. 54 of [Lyons, Caruana, Levy](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-71285-5) and p. 31 of [Friz, Hairer](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-71285-5).